# How to Turn JSON into a String?

Tags: python, json

Given input:

```
{"fruit": "apple"}
```

I need to generate the output:

```
{"Message":{\"fruit\": \"apple\"}}
```

It would be preferable to not run this through string replacements since the text may have quotation marks.

Here's my sample code:

```py
>>> import json
>>> 
>>> input={}
>>> input["fruit"]="apple"
>>> print(json.dumps(input))
{"fruit": "apple"}
>>> print(json.dumps(json.dumps(input)))
"{\"fruit\": \"apple\"}"                      # this looks right
>>> 
>>> output={}
>>> output["Message"]=json.dumps(json.dumps(input))
>>> print(output)
{'Message': '"{\\"fruit\\": \\"apple\\"}"'}    # unexpected
```

My hope was that the printed output of the double json.dumps would be what output's message field would be set to, but it added additional escapes.

So I tried this instead:

```py
>>> output["Message"]=json.dumps(input)
>>> print(output)
{'Message': '{"fruit": "apple"}'}
```

But it doesn't have the single escapes I'm looking for. How might I capture the single escapes when attempting to "stringify" this json?

Comment: That's the same thing. It's just the way `print()` prints dictionaries, because it shows the values using `repr()`, which doubles the backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to create a JSON string where the value of one property is an escaped JSON string, you simply create the JSON from your first dictionary and assign it to property of your "outer" dictionary and then create the JSON from that:

```
import json
d = {
    "Message": json.dumps( {"fruit": "apple"} )
}
print(json.dumps(d))
```

Output:

```
{"Message": "{\"fruit\": \"apple\"}"}
```

Note that you can not generate your desired output of `{"Message":{\"fruit\": \"apple\"}}` as this would not be valid JSON.

By the way, you do not "turn JSON into a string", because by definition, JSON is already a string.